# How to convert Video files into binary data format in android?

Tags: android, video-processing, binary-data

I had tried some thing in process for converting video files into binary data format. But i couldn't get it. Any one please help me to solve this, code below. 
here i this code i'm getting a video file form the sdcard using file option, In the bytearray i'm trying to assign the values retrieved from file in a buffer, then i'm displaying the contents present in that bytearray.

```
    Button bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            File file = new File("/mnt/sdcard/myvideo.mp4");
            FileInputStream objFileIS = null;
            try 
            {
                objFileIS = new FileInputStream(file);
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ByteArrayOutputStream objByteArrayOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] byteBufferString = new byte[1024];
            try 
            {
                for (int readNum; (readNum = objFileIS.read(byteBufferString)) != -1;) 
                {
                 objByteArrayOS.write(byteBufferString, 0, readNum);
                 System.out.println("read " + readNum + " bytes,");
                }
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }                    
            byte[] byteBinaryData = Base64.encode((objByteArrayOS.toByteArray()), Base64.DEFAULT);
            String strAttachmentCoded = new String(byteBinaryData);
            System.out.println(strAttachmentCoded);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), strAttachmentCoded ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     
        }
    });
```

Comment: Trying to display Base64 encoding of a video file in Toast is very strange idea. What's the problem you "couldn't get" ?

Comment: No, thats not my actual task, but i need to know whether the video is converted to binary format.

Comment: What means "*converted*" ? `objByteArrayOS` holds your file in binary format, yes. As it is stored on the SD card. But there is no "*conversion*" going on. What "*conversion*" would you like to happen?